# Find the maximum and minimum radii vectors of section of the surface $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2$ by the plane $lx+my+nz=0$

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Find the maximum and minimum radii vectors of section of the surface.

$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2=a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2$ by the plane $lx+my+nz=0$

I formed an expression $F=x^2+y^2+z^2 + \alpha((x^2+y^2+z^2)^2-a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2) + \beta(lx+my+nz).$ I partially differentiated the expression wrt $x,y$ and $z$, and equated it to $0$ to obtain the stationary points. I obtained $\alpha=-\frac{1}{r^2}$, and $\beta=\frac{2a^2lx+2b^2my+2c^2nz}{-r^2(l^2+m^2+n^2)}$ where $r=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$.

I also found $x=\frac{-\beta lr^2}{2(a^2-r^2)}, y=\frac{-\beta mr^2}{2(b^2-r^2)}$ and $z=\frac{-\beta nr^2}{2(c^2-r^2)}$.
On substituting the value of $\beta$ the expression for $x,y$ and $z$ gets even more complex. I am not able to find $x,y$ and $z$ individually.

If anyone can help me with a solution for this by Lagrange's multiplier method, I would be really happy.

Comment: I have linked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336255/find-the-maximum-or-minimum-values-of-x2-y2-z2-subject-to-the-condition) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386176/find-the-maximum-and-minimum-radii-vectors-of-section-of-the-surface-x2y2z) questions 
because their subject are similar

Comment: , whereas [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386176/find-the-maximum-and-minimum-radii-vectors-of-section-of-the-surface-x2y2z/2389491#2389491) with geometric interpretation and [Will Jagy’s analytical answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336255/find-the-maximum-or-minimum-values-of-x2-y2-z2-subject-to-the-condition/2336265#2336265) are complementary. Maybe later I’ll find how we can simplify the analytical calculations.

Answer (score 2):

I expect we can solve this problem using its geometrical interpretation.

As the radius ($r(x,y,z)$) we’ll be understand a distance from a point $(x,y,z)$ ofm the section to the origin $(0,0,0)$. Then the minimum radius is zero, because the section contains the origin.

To find the maximum radius we’ll proceed as follows. The left hand side of the surface equation is $r^4$. With this value fixed the right hand side of the equality is an equation of an ellipsoid (provided all $a,b,c$ are non-zero). Its intersection with the plane given by the equation $lx+my+nz=0$ is an ellipse (this intersection should be an ellipse even if one of $a,b,c$ is zero and I’ll skip the remaining degenerate cases). Now the equality between the left hand side and the right hand side of the equation describes the intersection of the ellipse with the circle of radius $r^2$ centered at the origin. Since when $r$ tends to the infinity, the left hand side describes the family of circles homothetic with the coefficient $r^2$ and the center at the origin, whereas the right hand describes the family of ellipses homothetic with the coefficient $r$ and the same center, eventually the intersection will be empty, and the maximum $r$ for which it is non-empty is attained when the endpoints of the big axis of the ellipse are exactly at the distance $r^2$ from the origin. This is a geometric condition for the maximum radius of the section, which should be converted to an analytical one.

> I am stuck at this problem since 2 days.

Your are too hasty. I have problems at which I am stuck from the former millennium. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the alternate solution. But I wanted to find the  fault in my line of thought.

Comment: Haha, and nice thought in the end, but I like to get my problems out of the way as soon as possible :)

Comment: @user467745 There maybe no fault. Lagrange multipliers method more or less often leads to too complicated expressions, so then we need to use other solution methods.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. But because of certain reasons, I want the solution by Lagrange's multiplier method only. I should've mentioned this in the question. I will make an edit.

Comment: @user467745 Then you can try to continue your solution with an aid of soft like MatLab, Mathcad or with Wolfram Alpha (which is available online), but I am pessimistic about the form of the final result.