# Using Lagrange's multiplier method, find the shortest distance between the line y=10-2x and the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

> Using Lagrange's multiplier method, find the shortest distance between the line $y=10-2x$ and the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$.

My work: 
Let the point on ellipse be $(2\cos\theta, 3\sin\theta)$

Let $F=(x-2\cos\theta)^2+(y-3\sin\theta)^2+\alpha(2x+y-10)$.

I partially diffentiated $F$ wrt $x$,$y$ and $\theta$ equated to $0$.

I get $\tan\theta=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\alpha=-2$

The point on ellipse I get is $(\frac{8}{5},\frac{9}{5})$ and the point on line I get is $(\frac {18}{5}, \frac{14}{5})$

Is this method correct? Can I take $\theta$ to be an independent variable, and differentiate wrt to it?

Comment: I think your way is beautiful! I checked your answer. It's right for the point on ellipse. I think here is a  typo in the second point.  You can take θ to be an independent variable, of course. The answer should be $\sqrt5$.

Comment: Corrected it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcame!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although your solution method is fine, I suspect that whoever gave you this exercise intended for you to use the equation of the ellipse directly instead of parameterizing the curve. Once you’ve done the latter, you have a single-variable problem for which there’s not much point in using a Lagrange multiplier: you can compute the distance of the parameterized point to the line and minimize that directly.

The intended solution is likely something along these lines: The square of the distance from a point $(x,y)$ to the line is given by $$f:(x,y)\mapsto{(2x+y-10)^2\over5}.$$ You are to minimize this function subject to the constraint $g(x,y)=0$, where $g:(x,y)\mapsto\frac{x^2}4+\frac{y^2}9-1$, so form the function $F:(x,y,\lambda)\mapsto f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y)$, set the partial derivatives of $F$ to zero and solve for $x$, $y$, $\lambda$. This will give you critical points of $f$ that you’ll still have to test to see which are minima.

Comment: Yes, you are so right! Thank you! Could you take a look at this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386176/find-the-maximum-and-minimum-radii-vectors-of-section-of-the-surface-x2y2z) as well? I always seems to run into a dead wall when there are two constraints involved. Can this not be solved manually using Lagrange's multiplier method as some answerers have suggested?

Comment: @amd Its been a long time and I don't if I get a reply but still I solved using your supposition of f(x,y) and g(x,y) but I am not able to reach the solution. If you can edit your answer and let me know the steps it would be really helpful

Comment: Can someone elaborate why the distance from a point to the line is given by f (given  above)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be
$$F=(x-t)^2+(y-s)^2+\alpha(2x+y-10)+\beta\left(\frac{t^2}{4}+\frac{s^2}{9}-1\right),$$
but I think it's better to solve your problem without Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Yes I took the wrong expression. I have made the edit, could you please check?

Comment: @user467745 Do it!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: you can find the tangent line to the ellipse that is parallel to the line $y=10-2x$.

The tangent line to the ellipse at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ must have the slope $-2$:
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}\right)'_x=(1)'_x \Rightarrow \frac{x}{2}+\frac{2y}{9}y'=0 \Rightarrow y'=-\frac{9x}{4y} \Rightarrow$$
$$y'(x_0)=-\frac{9x_0}{\pm 4\cdot3\sqrt{1-\frac{x_0^2}{4}}}=-2 \Rightarrow x_0=\pm\frac{8}{5} \Rightarrow y_0=\pm\frac95.$$
Note: In general, there can be two tangent lines and $x_0=-\frac85,y_0=-\frac95$ must be ignored as it is the furthest point from the given line (i.e. the max distance).

Then you should find the distance from the point $(\frac85,\frac95)$ of ellipse to the line $y=10-2x$.

Comment: Thank you for this alternate solution. This was quite simple.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9}$ can be made into $ 1 = 9x^2 + 4y^2 = 36 $ which can be made into $9cos^2(\theta) + 4sin^2(\theta) = 36$. This should help simplify your calculations.

Comment: Thank you! I used your substitution for my solution