# Find the maximum and minimum values of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to the condition $ax^2+by^2+cz^2 =1\;\;$ and $\;\;lz+my+ny=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

> Find the maximum and minimum values of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to the
>   condition $ax^2+by^2+cz^2 =1\;\;$ and   $\;\;lz+my+ny=0$ and interpret
>   the result geometrically

I started with Lagrange's method and Let $F = x^2+y^2+z^2+\lambda(lz+my+ny)\;\;$ . I found $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = F_x = 2x+\lambda(l)=0\;\;$ therefore $x=-(\lambda*l)/2\;\;$ and similarly I found $y,z\;\;$ . I substituted these values in $ax^2+by^2+cz^2 =1\;\;for \;\lambda$ and therefore $\lambda = \frac{2}{\sqrt{al^2+bm^2+cn^2}}$ .

Therefore $x=\frac{-l}{\sqrt{\sum al^2}},$ $y=\frac{-m}{\sqrt{\sum al^2}}$ $z=\frac{-n}{\sqrt{\sum al^2}}$ and the Max value of $\;\;x^2+y^2+z^2\;\;$ is $\frac{l^2+m^2+n^2}{\sqrt{al^2+bm^2+cn^2}}$ .

But when I substitute the values of $x,y,z$ back into $\;\;lz+my+ny$ I am not getting zero, therefore I made a mistake somewhere . Can someone give the solution and also the geometric interpretation.

Comment: If you are using Lagrange multipliers, you need two of them, not one, as you have two constraints.

Comment: Shouldn't the second condition be $l\color{red}{x}+my+n\color{red}{z}=0$? At least your calculations correspond to this.

Comment: It is $lx+my+nz=0$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2336255/265466, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2386176/265466 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2336255/265466. It’s hard to decide which one of them to use as the original for a duplicate since each answers only one part of your two-part question.

Answer (score 2):

You have two constraints, so you should have two Lagrange multipliers.  Look at the example at the bottom of [this page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx) from Paul's online math notes.

The geometric interpretation is easy.  The constraints describe a quadric surface and a plane, so we are looking for a point on their intersection.  Since we are optimizing $x^2+y^2+z^2,$ we are looking for the maximum and minimum distances from that intersection curve to the origin.

Comment: @amd You're right, my bad.